# How to emphasize holidays by color in `cal` command

Tags: cal

I want to emphasize holidays by color in `cal` or similar command.

I'm using OS X and Ubuntu 14, is there easy way to enable the function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it is possible for standard `cal`, but you may want to take a look at `gcal`, the [GNU calendar](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/).

To highlight the text you need to pass `-H` option:

```
-H text
--highlighting=text
    Set highlighting sequence / marking character pairs explicitly.
    In this sense, highlighting sequences are control character sequences 
    which cause a color or intensity switch in output text. Typical control 
    character sequences are the ANSI escape sequences [...]
```

There is even exactly highlighting holidays example in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/manual/html_node/Global-options.html#Global-options):

```
For example:

-H \x20:\x20:\x1:# respectively
--highlighting=\x20:\x20:\x1:#
marks the actual day like ‘\x20actual date\x20’6 and the holiday date like 
‘\x1holiday date#’ using the given marking characters. 

-H \x1b[34;42m:\x1b[0;40m or
-H \033[34;42m:\033[0;40m or
-H \E[34;42m:\E[0;40m
defines a starting ANSI escape highlighting sequence ‘\x1b[34;42m’ used for 
actual day and ending ANSI escape highlighting sequence ‘\x1b[0;40m’ with no 
given highlighting sequence for holidays, so default highlighting sequences for 
holidays are used (non-given entries are always skipped).
```

---

Example:

- To highlight current day in blue, and holidays for United States/Alaska (US_AK) in green for current month:

  ```
  gcal -H '\e[34m:\e[0m:\e[32m:\e[0m' -q US_AK
  ```

  Note: `34` is ANSI code for foreground blue, and `32` is ANSI code for foreground green

  The results:

  [image]
- To display current day in red (`31`) on green background (`42`) and Chinese (`CN`) holidays in yellow (`33`) on magenta (`45`) for whole 2014

  ```
  gcal -H '\e[31;42m:\e[0m:\e[33;45m:\e[0m' -q CN 2014
  ```

You will find all country codes in `info gcal` under description of `-q` option.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I installed `gcal` and try `gcal -H "\033[34;42m:\033[0;40m"`, it changes appearance a bit, but there is no color. I'll try it later in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Tetsu I've updated the answer with examples, hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: Great! Now it works as I expected.