# Calendar Highlight in UNIX

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, calendar

I have tried several but could not highlight multiple dates in year calendar

```
cal -y
2022                               

       January               February                 March       
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1          1  2  3  4  5          1  2  3  4  5   
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8    6  7  8  9 10 11 12    6  7  8  9 10 11 12   
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15   13 14 15 16 17 18 19   13 14 15 16 17 18 19   
16 17 18 19 20 21 22   20 21 22 23 24 25 26   20 21 22 23 24 25 26   
23 24 25 26 27 28 29   27 28                  27 28 29 30 31         
30 31                                                                
        April                   May                   June        
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                1  2    1  2  3  4  5  6  7             1  2  3  4   
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9    8  9 10 11 12 13 14    5  6  7  8  9 10 11   
10 11 12 13 14 15 16   15 16 17 18 19 20 21   12 13 14 15 16 17 18   
17 18 19 20 21 22 23   22 23 24 25 26 27 28   19 20 21 22 23 24 25   
24 25 26 27 28 29 30   29 30 31               26 27 28 29 30         
                                                                     
        July                  August                September     
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                1  2       1  2  3  4  5  6                1  2  3   
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9    7  8  9 10 11 12 13    4  5  6  7  8  9 10   
10 11 12 13 14 15 16   14 15 16 17 18 19 20   11 12 13 14 15 16 17   
17 18 19 20 21 22 23   21 22 23 24 25 26 27   18 19 20 21 22 23 24   
24 25 26 27 28 29 30   28 29 30 31            25 26 27 28 29 30      
31                                                                   
       October               November               December      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1          1  2  3  4  5                1  2  3   
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8    6  7  8  9 10 11 12    4  5  6  7  8  9 10   
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15   13 14 15 16 17 18 19   11 12 13 14 15 16 17   
16 17 18 19 20 21 22   20 21 22 23 24 25 26   18 19 20 21 22 23 24   
23 24 25 26 27 28 29   27 28 29 30            25 26 27 28 29 30 31   
30 31
```

I want to highlight multiple dates in the year calendar. Is it possible in UNIX?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Thought extracting the calendar in text file and using
Printf %s\\n "abc$(tput smso)def$(tput rmso)ghi".             But clearly not working to get exact date in file

Comment: `ncal` highlights current day. There is also an option (`-H`) to highlight a certain date. But I don't think it can be used for multiple highlights though.

Comment: What UNIX? Do you maybe mean Linux and not UNIX? What operating system are you using? Does this need to be highlighted in the terminal? Or in some GUI? Can you give an example?

Comment: Yeah linux.yeah needs to be highlighted in terminal.                               When we do a simple command  $cal -y 24 8 2022 we observe the given date has been highlighted. So when I get multiple dates in a file nd want to highlight all multiple dates in the year calendar above !!!!

Comment: Cal -y | grep -C6 --color "$(date +%e)". The output can be similar to that but it should be for all dates that I give in separate file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to emphasize holidays by color in \`cal\` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164555/how-to-emphasize-holidays-by-color-in-cal-command)

Answer (score 6):

You could write a script to tweak the `cal` output, e.g. using any awk:

```
$ cat tgtDates
January 25
June 13
```

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cal 2022 |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        highlightOn  = "["
        highlightOff = "]"
    }
    NR==FNR {
        tgtDates[$0]
        next
    }
    NF == 3  { split($0,months); print; next } # month list
    !/[0-9]/ { print; next }            # blank line or days list
    {                                   # dates list
        for ( mthNr=1; mthNr<=3; mthNr++ ) {
            mthName   = months[mthNr]
            inDayNrs  = substr($0,1,20)
            outDayNrs = ""
            while ( match(inDayNrs,/[0-9]+/) ) {
                inDayNr   = substr(inDayNrs,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                curDate   = mthName " " inDayNr
                outDayNr  = (curDate in tgtDates ? highlightOn inDayNr highlightOff : inDayNr )
                outDayNrs = outDayNrs substr(inDayNrs,1,RSTART-1) outDayNr
                inDayNrs  = substr(inDayNrs,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            }
            printf "%s   ", outDayNrs inDayNrs
            $0 = substr($0,24)
        }
        print ""
    }
' "$1" -
```

```
$ ./tst.sh tgtDates
                               2022
       January               February                 March
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1          1  2  3  4  5          1  2  3  4  5
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8    6  7  8  9 10 11 12    6  7  8  9 10 11 12
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15   13 14 15 16 17 18 19   13 14 15 16 17 18 19
16 17 18 19 20 21 22   20 21 22 23 24 25 26   20 21 22 23 24 25 26
23 24 [25] 26 27 28 29   27 28                  27 28 29 30 31
30 31
        April                   May                   June
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                1  2    1  2  3  4  5  6  7             1  2  3  4
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9    8  9 10 11 12 13 14    5  6  7  8  9 10 11
10 11 12 13 14 15 16   15 16 17 18 19 20 21   12 [13] 14 15 16 17 18
17 18 19 20 21 22 23   22 23 24 25 26 27 28   19 20 21 22 23 24 25
24 25 26 27 28 29 30   29 30 31               26 27 28 29 30

        July                  August                September
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                1  2       1  2  3  4  5  6                1  2  3
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9    7  8  9 10 11 12 13    4  5  6  7  8  9 10
10 11 12 13 14 15 16   14 15 16 17 18 19 20   11 12 13 14 15 16 17
17 18 19 20 21 22 23   21 22 23 24 25 26 27   18 19 20 21 22 23 24
24 25 26 27 28 29 30   28 29 30 31            25 26 27 28 29 30
31
       October               November               December
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa   Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1          1  2  3  4  5                1  2  3
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8    6  7  8  9 10 11 12    4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15   13 14 15 16 17 18 19   11 12 13 14 15 16 17
16 17 18 19 20 21 22   20 21 22 23 24 25 26   18 19 20 21 22 23 24
23 24 25 26 27 28 29   27 28 29 30            25 26 27 28 29 30 31
30 31
```

Obviously I'm just wrapping the target dates in `[...]` above so they are visible to show the command working and that's what causes the line layouts to move, to color the dates instead just change:

```
        highlightOn  = "["
        highlightOff = "]"
```

to something that'll change the background and/or foreground color for highlighting, and you can even set different background/foreground colors for whatever different types of events you like, e.g.:

```
$ cat tgtDates
January 25 Birthday
June 13 Meeting
September 2
December 25 Holiday
```

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cal 2022 |
awk -v today="$(date +'%B %-d')" '
    BEGIN {
        split("BLACK RED GREEN YELLOW BLUE MAGENTA CYAN WHITE",tputColors)
        for (i in tputColors) {
            colorName = tputColors[i]
            colorNr = i-1

            cmd = "tput setaf " colorNr
            fgEscSeq[colorName] = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<" colorName ">" )
            close(cmd)

            cmd = "tput setab " colorNr
            bgEscSeq[colorName] = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<" colorName ">" )
            close(cmd)
        }

        cmd = "tput sgr0"
        colorOff = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<sgr0>" )
        close(cmd)

        highlight["Today"]    = bgEscSeq["BLACK"]  fgEscSeq["WHITE"]
        highlight["Holiday"]  = bgEscSeq["RED"]    fgEscSeq["YELLOW"]
        highlight["Birthday"] = bgEscSeq["CYAN"]   fgEscSeq["RED"]
        highlight["Meeting"]  = bgEscSeq["YELLOW"] fgEscSeq["GREEN"]
        highlight[""]         = bgEscSeq["GREEN"]  fgEscSeq["WHITE"]

        tgtDates[today] = "Today"
    }
    NR==FNR {
        tgtDates[$1" "$2] = $3
        next
    }
    NF == 3  { split($0,months); print; next } # month list
    !/[0-9]/ { print; next }            # blank line or days list
    {                                   # dates list
        for ( mthNr=1; mthNr<=3; mthNr++ ) {
            mthName   = months[mthNr]
            inDayNrs  = substr($0,1,20)
            outDayNrs = ""
            while ( match(inDayNrs,/[0-9]+/) ) {
                inDayNr   = substr(inDayNrs,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                curDate   = mthName " " inDayNr
                highlightOn = highlightOff = ""
                if ( curDate in tgtDates ) {
                    dateType = tgtDates[curDate]
                    highlightOn = ( dateType in highlight ? highlight[dateType] : highlight[""] )
                    highlightOff = colorOff
                }
                outDayNr  = highlightOn inDayNr highlightOff
                outDayNrs = outDayNrs substr(inDayNrs,1,RSTART-1) outDayNr
                inDayNrs  = substr(inDayNrs,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            }
            printf "%s   ", outDayNrs inDayNrs
            $0 = substr($0,24)
        }
        print ""
    }
' "$1" -
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this awk script. It's great, but I had to make a couple of minor
adjustments for it to work in Ubuntu.  I've tested it with success in Ubuntu
20.04.4 LTS and in 18.04.6 LTS.

The changes made were: (in diff old new format)

```
2c2
< cal 2022 |
---
> ncal -bh 2022 |
55,56c55,56
<             printf "%s   ", outDayNrs inDayNrs
<             $0 = substr($0,24)
---
>             printf "%s  ", outDayNrs inDayNrs
>             $0 = substr($0,23)
```

For simplicity, here's the revision:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ncal -bh 2022 |
awk -v today="$(date +'%B %-d')" '
    BEGIN {
        split("BLACK RED GREEN YELLOW BLUE MAGENTA CYAN WHITE",tputColors)
        for (i in tputColors) {
            colorName = tputColors[i]
            colorNr = i-1

            cmd = "tput setaf " colorNr
            fgEscSeq[colorName] = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<" colorName ">" )
            close(cmd)

            cmd = "tput setab " colorNr
            bgEscSeq[colorName] = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<" colorName ">" )
            close(cmd)
        }

        cmd = "tput sgr0"
        colorOff = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<sgr0>" )
        close(cmd)

        highlight["Today"]    = bgEscSeq["BLACK"]  fgEscSeq["WHITE"]
        highlight["Holiday"]  = bgEscSeq["RED"]    fgEscSeq["YELLOW"]
        highlight["Birthday"] = bgEscSeq["CYAN"]   fgEscSeq["RED"]
        highlight["Meeting"]  = bgEscSeq["YELLOW"] fgEscSeq["GREEN"]
        highlight[""]         = bgEscSeq["GREEN"]  fgEscSeq["WHITE"]

        tgtDates[today] = "Today"
    }
    NR==FNR {
        tgtDates[$1" "$2] = $3
        next
    }
    NF == 3  { split($0,months); print; next } # month list
    !/[0-9]/ { print; next }            # blank line or days list
    {                                   # dates list
        for ( mthNr=1; mthNr<=3; mthNr++ ) {
            mthName   = months[mthNr]
            inDayNrs  = substr($0,1,20)
            outDayNrs = ""
            while ( match(inDayNrs,/[0-9]+/) ) {
                inDayNr   = substr(inDayNrs,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                curDate   = mthName " " inDayNr
                highlightOn = highlightOff = ""
                if ( curDate in tgtDates ) {
                    dateType = tgtDates[curDate]
                    highlightOn = ( dateType in highlight ? highlight[dateType] : highlight[""] )
                    highlightOff = colorOff
                }
                outDayNr  = highlightOn inDayNr highlightOff
                outDayNrs = outDayNrs substr(inDayNrs,1,RSTART-1) outDayNr
                inDayNrs  = substr(inDayNrs,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            }
            printf "%s  ", outDayNrs inDayNrs
            $0 = substr($0,23)
        }
        print ""
    }
' "$1" -
```