# awk statement to print char variable number of times not working

Tags: awk

I have the following to print a dashed line based on the longest line of a csv file:

```
awk -F ',' '
    BEGIN {
       longest_line=0
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
           longest[i] = ""
        }
    }
    {
       for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
           if (length($i) > length(longest[i])) {
               longest[i] = $i
           }
       }
    }
    
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) {
            longest_line += length(longest[i])
        }
        printf("%*s", longest_line, "=")
    }
'
```

Here's the entire script:

```
awk -F ',' -v smso="$smso" -v rmso="$rmso" 'BEGIN {
    count=1
    firstcol=0
    arraylen=1
    longest_line=0
   for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
       longest[i] = ""
    }
}

{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            if (i==NF) {
                data[arraylen++]=$i
                data[arraylen++]="\n"
            } else {
                data[arraylen++]=$i
            }
    }
}


{
   for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
       if (length($i) > length(longest[i])) {
           longest[i] = $i
       }
   }
}

END {
    for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) {
        longest_line += length(longest[i])
    }
    printf("%*s", longest_line, "b")
    for (i = 1; i <= length(data); i++) {
        if (data[i]=="\n") {
            firstcol++
           count=1  
            printf("%s", data[i])
        } else if (count==1 && i != 1) {
            printf("%s%s%s", "|", data[i], "|")
            count++
        } else {
            smso=$(tput smso)
            rmso=$(tput rmso)
            num_spaces=(length(longest[count])-length(data[i]))+1
            printf("%s%*s%s%s", (i==1?"|":""), (i==1?num_spaces-1:num_spaces), " ", firstcol==0?toupper(data[i]):data[i], "|")
            count++
        }
    }   
}'
```

input file is:

```
NUMBER,FNAME,LNAME,PHONE-TYPE:GROUPS
222-222-2222,Elizabeth,Taylor,office:beauty:
111-111-1111,Matt,Alex,personal:superhuman:cool:amazing:extra
```

and desired output is:

```
==============================================================
|      NUMBER|     FNAME|  LNAME|           PHONE-TYPE:GROUPS|
|222-222-2222| Elizabeth| Taylor|              office:beauty:|
|111-111-1111|      Matt|   Alex| personal:cool:amazing:extra|
```

but my output is:

```
                                                             =
|      NUMBER|     FNAME|  LNAME|           PHONE-TYPE:GROUPS|
|222-222-2222| Elizabeth| Taylor|              office:beauty:|
|111-111-1111|      Matt|   Alex| personal:cool:amazing:extra|
```

Comment: Unrelated to this question but `smso=$(tput smso)` is shell syntax. Awk is not shell. You can't directly call arbitrary Unix commands like `tput` from awk any more than you could call them directly from `C`. You should ask a new question about that if you can't figure out how to do whatever it is you're trying to do there (I personally have posted several answers on this forum for how to use `tput` with awk_shell so look in the archives).

Comment: I was actually going to inquire about that as well haha. I was trying to bold the first row as thats where the column titles are. Any idea how I'd do that in awk?

Comment: Regarding using `tput` or otherwise coloring output with `awk`, see these for some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64046525/1745001, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669122/133219, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/691810/133219.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("%*s", longest_line, "=")
```

prints a `=` character indented by `longest_line-1` blanks. You want this instead:

```
line = sprintf("%*s", longest_line, "")
gsub(/ /,"=",line)
print line
```

FWIW this is how I'd write the code to do what you appear to be trying to do, using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="|"; hdrChar="=" }
{
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=NF; colNr++) {
        val = $colNr
        vals[NR,colNr] = val
        wid = length(val)
        wids[colNr] = (wid > wids[colNr] ? wid : wids[colNr])
    }
}
END {
    for ( colNr=1; colNr<=NF; colNr++ ) {
        row = row hdrChar sprintf("%*s",wids[colNr],"")
    }
    gsub(/ /,hdrChar,row)
    print row hdrChar

    for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=NR; rowNr++ ) {
        row = ""
        for ( colNr=1; colNr<=NF; colNr++ ) {
            row = row OFS sprintf("%*s",wids[colNr],vals[rowNr,colNr])
        }
        print row OFS
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
======================================================================
|      NUMBER|    FNAME| LNAME|                     PHONE-TYPE:GROUPS|
|222-222-2222|Elizabeth|Taylor|                        office:beauty:|
|111-111-1111|     Matt|  Alex|personal:superhuman:cool:amazing:extra|
```

Pad some fields with spaces as you see fit by changing `val = $colNr` to `val = " " $colNr " "` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

`sprintf("%*s", n, string)` left-pads the string to a length (in number of bytes or characters depending on the  `awk` implementation)  of `n` *with spaces*.

To repeat a string n times, you could write a helper function:

```
function repeat(n, string,  result) {
  while (n-- > 0) result = result string
  return result
}
```

Here, I'd suggest using `mlr` which does that (or something similar) out of the box (and processes CSVs correctly):

```
$ mlr --c2p --barred cat file.csv
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------+
| NUMBER       | FNAME     | LNAME  | PHONE-TYPE:GROUPS                      |
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------+
| 222-222-2222 | Elizabeth | Taylor | office:beauty:                         |
| 111-111-1111 | Matt      | Alex   | personal:superhuman:cool:amazing:extra |
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------+
```

Or for right-aligned fields:

```
$ mlr --c2p --barred --right cat file.csv
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------+
|       NUMBER |     FNAME |  LNAME |                      PHONE-TYPE:GROUPS |
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------+
| 222-222-2222 | Elizabeth | Taylor |                         office:beauty: |
| 111-111-1111 |      Matt |   Alex | personal:superhuman:cool:amazing:extra |
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------+
```

If `mlr` is not available, rather than `awk`, I'd use `perl` which has largely superseded `awk`.

```
perl -MList::Util=zip -MTerm::ANSIColor -F, -lane '
  push @rows, [@F];
  $i = 0; for (@F) {
    $max[$i] = length if length > $max[$i];
    $i++;
  }
  
  END {
    $line = join("+", "", (map {"-" x ($_ + 2)} @max), "");
    print $line;
    print join("|", "", (map {colored(sprintf(" %*s ", @$_), "bold blue")} zip(\@max, shift @rows)), "");
    print $line;
    for (@rows) {
      print join("|", "", (map {sprintf " %*s ", @$_} zip(\@max, $_)), "");
    }
    print $line;
  }' file.csv
```

Which gives:

```
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------+
|       NUMBER |     FNAME |  LNAME |                      PHONE-TYPE:GROUPS |
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------+
| 222-222-2222 | Elizabeth | Taylor |                         office:beauty: |
| 111-111-1111 |      Matt |   Alex | personal:superhuman:cool:amazing:extra |
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------+
```

With the headers in bold and blue.

In `perl`, repeating strings is done with the `x` repetition operator: `"string" x 3`  results in `stringstringstring`. See `perldoc perlop`  for details.

Though in `perl` you rarely need  to reinvent the wheel as in the 35 years it's been around, perl modules have been written for about anything. We've already used the [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) module with some useful list manipulation functions and [`Term::ANSIColor`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor) to output coloured text above, but there's also a [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module to process CSVs and [`Text::ASCIITable`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ASCIITable) to format tables:

```
$ perl -MText::CSV=csv -MText::ASCIITable -e '
  $c = csv(in => shift);
  $t = Text::ASCIITable->new;
  $t->setCols(shift @$c);
  $t->addRow($_) for @$c;
  print $t' file.csv
.----------------------------------------------------------------------------.
| NUMBER       | FNAME     | LNAME  | PHONE-TYPE:GROUPS                      |
+--------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------+
| 222-222-2222 | Elizabeth | Taylor | office:beauty:                         |
| 111-111-1111 | Matt      | Alex   | personal:superhuman:cool:amazing:extra |
'--------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------'
```

Comment: I wasnt aware of mlr but this was more of a personal challenge because I'm trying to get better with awk