How to modify a part of an output of pacinfo in bash?
Having an example output of pacinfo local/puddletag like this:
Name:           puddletag
Base:           puddletag
Repository:     local
Version:        2.3.0-2
Description:    An audio tag editor for GNU/Linux
Architecture:   any
URL:            https://docs.puddletag.net/
Licenses:       GPL-3.0-or-later
Groups:         modified
Requires:       python-certifi
Requires:       python-charset-normalizer
Requires:       python-configobj
Requires:       python-distro
Requires:       python-idna
Requires:       python-mutagen
Requires:       python-pyparsing
Requires:       python-pyqt5
Requires:       python-rapidfuzz
Requires:       python-requests
Requires:       python-six
Requires:       python-unidecode
Requires:       python-urllib3
Requires:       qt5-svg
Optional Deps:  python-levenshtein: faster duplicate matching
Optional Deps:  python-lxml: additional tag sources
Optional Deps:  python-pyacoustid: AcoustID support
Optional Deps:  python-audioread
Optional Deps:  quodlibet: QuodLibet library support
Package Size:   0.00 B
Download Size:  0.00 B
Installed Size: 4.84 M
Packager:       Tomasz "Ludvick" Niedzielski <ludvick0@gmail.com>
Build Date:     2024-05-11 03:22:46
Install Date:   2024-05-11 03:23:57
Install Script: No
Install Reason: Dependency
Validated By:   SHA-256
Validated By:   Signature

I'd like to get:
Name:           puddletag
Base:           puddletag
Repository:     local
Version:        2.3.0-2
Description:    An audio tag editor for GNU/Linux
Architecture:   any
URL:            https://docs.puddletag.net/
Licenses:       GPL-3.0-or-later
Groups:         modified
Requires:       python-certifi python-charset-normalizer python-configobj python-distro python-idna python-mutagen python-pyparsing python-pyqt5 python-rapidfuzz python-requests python-six python-unidecode python-urllib3 qt5-svg
Optional Deps:  python-levenshtein: faster duplicate matching
                python-lxml: additional tag sources
                python-pyacoustid: AcoustID support
                python-audioread
                quodlibet: QuodLibet library support
Package Size:   0.00 B
Download Size:  0.00 B
Installed Size: 4.84 M
Packager:       Tomasz "Ludvick" Niedzielski <ludvick0@gmail.com>
Build Date:     2024-05-11 03:22:46
Install Date:   2024-05-11 03:23:57
Install Script: No
Install Reason: Dependency
Validated By:   SHA-256
Validated By:   Signature

Please, help...

What exact output do you want? Should we really add (...) to the output? If not, what is that supposed to be? Do you only want the Requires and Optional Deps lines and nothing else? Do you want all lines but with repeated first fields removed?  And what is the command you are parsing, pacinfo what? We need to be able to reproduce this.

Sorry for messing up text... (...) means that there is rest of the pacinfo's output

Finally modified my whole question following your remarks.

Using any POSIX awk:
$ cat tst.awk
{
    match($0,/:[[:space:]]*/)
    nextTag = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    if ( nextTag != tag ) {
        if ( NR > 1 ) {
            prt()
        }
        numVals = 0
        tag = nextTag
    }
    valInBeg = RSTART + RLENGTH
    vals[++numVals] = substr($0,valInBeg)
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   i, pfx) {
    pfx[0] = sprintf("%-*s", valInBeg-1, tag ":")
    if ( tag == "Requires" ) {
        pfx[1] = OFS
    }
    else if ( tag == "Optional Deps" ) {
        pfx[1] = ORS sprintf("%*s", valInBeg-1, "")
    }
    else {
        pfx[1] = ORS pfx[0]
    }
    for ( i=1; i<=numVals; i++ ) {
        printf "%s%s%s", pfx[(i>1)], vals[i], (i<numVals ? "" : ORS)
    }
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file
Name:           puddletag
Base:           puddletag
Repository:     local
Version:        2.3.0-2
Description:    An audio tag editor for GNU/Linux
Architecture:   any
URL:            https://docs.puddletag.net/
Licenses:       GPL-3.0-or-later
Groups:         modified
Requires:       python-certifi python-charset-normalizer python-configobj python-distro python-idna python-mutagen python-pyparsing python-pyqt5 python-rapidfuzz python-requests python-six python-unidecode python-urllib3 qt5-svg
Optional Deps:  python-levenshtein: faster duplicate matching
                python-lxml: additional tag sources
                python-pyacoustid: AcoustID support
                python-audioread
                quodlibet: QuodLibet library support
Package Size:   0.00 B
Download Size:  0.00 B
Installed Size: 4.84 M
Packager:       Tomasz "Ludvick" Niedzielski <ludvick0@gmail.com>
Build Date:     2024-05-11 03:22:46
Install Date:   2024-05-11 03:23:57
Install Script: No
Install Reason: Dependency
Validated By:   SHA-256
Validated By:   Signature

and with the file expected containing the expected output copy/pasted from your question:
$ awk -f tst.awk file > actual
$ diff expected actual
$

so we know the above does produce the expected output.

Original answer to the OPs original version of the question:
Using any POSIX awk and assuming you don't REALLY have those (...) lines in your input (if you do it's a trivial tweak to handle them):
$ cat tst.awk
{
    match($0,/:[[:space:]]*/)
    nextTag = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    if ( nextTag != tag ) {
        if ( NR > 1 ) {
            prt()
        }
        numVals = 0
        tag = nextTag
    }
    valInBeg = RSTART + RLENGTH
    vals[++numVals] = substr($0,valInBeg)
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   i, pfx) {
    pfx[0] = sprintf("%-*s: ", valInBeg-1, tag)
    pfx[1] = ( vals[1] ~ /:/ ? sprintf("%s%*s", ORS, valInBeg+1, "") : OFS )
    for ( i=1; i<=numVals; i++ ) {
        printf "%s%s%s", pfx[(i>1)], vals[i], (i<numVals ? "" : ORS)
    }
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file
Requires        : python-certifi python-charset-normalizer python-configobj python-distro python-idna python-mutagen python-pyparsing python-pyqt5 python-rapidfuzz python-requests python-six python-unidecode python-urllib3 qt5-svg
Optional Deps   : python-levenshtein: faster duplicate matching
                  python-lxml: additional tag sources
                  python-pyacoustid: AcoustID support
                  python-audioread
                  quodlibet: QuodLibet library support


thank you for your answer and your time spent for it. For the moment I'm away from my komputer (until beginning of June). I'll check if your solution does what i need and let you know.

Thank you for your code it works just great! How could it be modifiet to get output like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p-0q-sg8IV4SCua0Gw5fiPBaQJbckKeC/view?usp=sharing? I mean colours of text and all collons placed vertically aligned...

You're welcome. I put my original answer back at the bottom of the latest one as your original question had expected output that showed all the :s lined up so that's what my original answer did. To color the output see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669122/133219, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/691810/133219, and/or https://stackoverflow.com/a/77971524/1745001. If you can't solve your new problem from that then post a new question showing your attempted code and sample input/output for that new problem.

Thank you soooooooo much! In the meanwhile I sorted out with the colorizing output. BTW: asking my original question, I hopet i was able to find solution for lined up :, but it occured not so easy as I supposed. All in all - once more thank you!

You're welcome. Lining up the :s WAS easy (measure the indent before the 2nd field in the input and stick the : there in the output), I had already shown that in my original answer before you changed the sample input/output in your question and so removed that requirement.

I've just asked another question that is similar to this one https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/777863/573793 Could you, please, have a look in a free while? Thank you in advance.
