how to omit/ignore/remove lines starting with local/ using awk
Variable _RESULT contains an output of pacinfo --verbose local/jre.
Using awk script (by Ed Morton - thanks to him!):
awk '{
      match($0,/:[[:space:]]*/)
      nextTag = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
      if ( nextTag != tag )
      {
              if ( NR > 1 )
              {
                      prt()
              }
              numVals = 0
              tag = nextTag
      }
      valInBeg = RSTART + RLENGTH
      vals[++numVals] = substr($0,valInBeg)
      }
      END { prt() }

      function prt(   i, pfx) {
      pfx[0] = sprintf("%-*s: ", valInBeg-1, tag)
      pfx[1] = ( vals[1] ~ /[/]|:/ ? sprintf("%s%*s", ORS, valInBeg+1, "") : OFS )
      for ( i=1; i<=numVals; i++ )
      {
      printf "%s%s%s", pfx[(i>1)], vals[i], (i<numVals ? "" : ORS)
      }
}' <<<$_RESULT

I got:
Name            : jre
Base            : jdk
Repository      : ls-aur
File            : jre-22.0.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
Version         : 22.0.1-2
Description     : Oracle Java Runtime Environment
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://www.oracle.com/java/
Licenses        : LicenseRef-custom
Provides        : java-runtime=22 java-runtime-jdk22 jre22-jdk=22.0.1-2 java-runtime-headless=22 java-runtime-headless-jdk=22 jre22-jdk-headless=22.0.1-2
Requires        : java-runtime-common ca-certificates-utils freetype2 libx11 libxext libxi libxtst libxrender
Optional Deps   : alsa-lib: for basic sound support
                  gtk2: for the Gtk+ 2 look and feel - desktop usage
                  gtk3: for the Gtk+ 3 look and feel - desktop usage
Conflicts       : jdk
Required By     : extra/bcprov
                  extra/beanshell
                  extra/cfr
                  extra/dbeaver
                  extra/ditaa
                  extra/eclipse-ecj
                  extra/freecol
                  extra/freeplane
                  extra/geogebra
                  extra/geotag
                  extra/gpsprune
                  extra/jadx
                  extra/java-avalon-framework
                  extra/java-batik
                  extra/java-commons-daemon
                  extra/java-commons-io
                  extra/java-commons-lang
                  extra/java-commons-logging
                  extra/java-hamcrest
                  extra/java-jline
                  extra/java-rhino
                  extra/java-rxtx
                  extra/java-xmlgraphics-commons
                  extra/jlatexmath
                  extra/jmol
                  extra/josm
                  extra/jruby
                  extra/keycloak-hcaptcha
                  extra/keycloak-metrics-spi
                  extra/kotlin
                  extra/ktlint
                  extra/languagetool
                  extra/leiningen
                  extra/libreoffice-extension-writer2latex
                  extra/pdftk
                  extra/perl-inline-java
                  extra/plantuml
                  extra/plantuml
                  extra/plantuml-server
                  extra/plantuml-server
                  extra/procyon-decompiler
                  extra/protege
                  extra/sbt
                  extra/schemacrawler
                  extra/sdedit
                  extra/shattered-pixel-dungeon
                  extra/sweethome3d
                  extra/tomcat10
                  extra/tomcat8
                  extra/tomcat9
                  extra/zaproxy
Optional For    : local/libbluray: BD-J library
                  local/libjpeg-turbo: for TurboJPEG Java wrapper
                  local/libjxl: for JNI bindings
                  local/libreoffice-fresh: adds java support
                  local/opencv: Java interface
                  extra/bettercap-caplets: java caplets
                  extra/brltty: Java support
                  extra/csound: java integration
                  extra/facter: jruby support
                  extra/languagetool: needed for the GUI version
                  extra/libbluray: BD-J library
                  extra/libguestfs: for Java bindings
                  extra/libjpeg-turbo: for TurboJPEG Java wrapper
                  extra/libjxl: for JNI bindings
                  extra/libreoffice-fresh: adds java support
                  extra/libreoffice-still: adds java support
                  extra/libsvm: for java bindings
                  extra/nomad: for java driver
                  extra/nomad: for java driver - headless
                  extra/octave: java support
                  extra/opencv: Java interface
                  extra/opencv-cuda: Java interface
                  extra/polymake: java module
                  extra/ruby-concurrent: jruby support
                  extra/spring: java-based bots
                  extra/swi-prolog: for using Prolog from Java
                  extra/texlive-binextra: for utilities like arara, texplate
                  extra/texlive-latexextra: for pdfannotextractor
MakeDep For     : extra/chromium
                  extra/cvc4
                  extra/electron23
                  extra/electron27
                  extra/electron28
                  extra/electron29
                  extra/electron30
                  extra/mysql-workbench
Package Size    : 41.18 M
Download Size   : 0.00 B
Installed Size  : 187.41 M
Packager        : Tomasz "Ludvick" Niedzielski <ludvick0@gmail.com>
Build Date      : 2024-04-27 18:28:47
SHA-256 Sum     : 0774c9869fea600a38be28641ffaa5fea27befd820801960b5f8f019102f6962

How to modify above awk script, to remove/omit lines that start with local/ and, I suppose, might appear in other section too. I mean in Required By and/or in MakeDep For.
And finally get this:
Name            : jre
Base            : jdk
Repository      : ls-aur
File            : jre-22.0.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
Version         : 22.0.1-2
Description     : Oracle Java Runtime Environment
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://www.oracle.com/java/
Licenses        : LicenseRef-custom
Provides        : java-runtime=22 java-runtime-jdk22 jre22-jdk=22.0.1-2 java-runtime-headless=22 java-runtime-headless-jdk=22 jre22-jdk-headless=22.0.1-2
Requires        : java-runtime-common ca-certificates-utils freetype2 libx11 libxext libxi libxtst libxrender
Optional Deps   : alsa-lib: for basic sound support
                  gtk2: for the Gtk+ 2 look and feel - desktop usage
                  gtk3: for the Gtk+ 3 look and feel - desktop usage
Conflicts       : jdk
Required By     : extra/bcprov
                  extra/beanshell
                  extra/cfr
                  extra/dbeaver
                  extra/ditaa
                  extra/eclipse-ecj
                  extra/freecol
                  extra/freeplane
                  extra/geogebra
                  extra/geotag
                  extra/gpsprune
                  extra/jadx
                  extra/java-avalon-framework
                  extra/java-batik
                  extra/java-commons-daemon
                  extra/java-commons-io
                  extra/java-commons-lang
                  extra/java-commons-logging
                  extra/java-hamcrest
                  extra/java-jline
                  extra/java-rhino
                  extra/java-rxtx
                  extra/java-xmlgraphics-commons
                  extra/jlatexmath
                  extra/jmol
                  extra/josm
                  extra/jruby
                  extra/keycloak-hcaptcha
                  extra/keycloak-metrics-spi
                  extra/kotlin
                  extra/ktlint
                  extra/languagetool
                  extra/leiningen
                  extra/libreoffice-extension-writer2latex
                  extra/pdftk
                  extra/perl-inline-java
                  extra/plantuml
                  extra/plantuml
                  extra/plantuml-server
                  extra/plantuml-server
                  extra/procyon-decompiler
                  extra/protege
                  extra/sbt
                  extra/schemacrawler
                  extra/sdedit
                  extra/shattered-pixel-dungeon
                  extra/sweethome3d
                  extra/tomcat10
                  extra/tomcat8
                  extra/tomcat9
                  extra/zaproxy
Optional For    : extra/bettercap-caplets: java caplets
                  extra/brltty: Java support
                  extra/csound: java integration
                  extra/facter: jruby support
                  extra/languagetool: needed for the GUI version
                  extra/libbluray: BD-J library
                  extra/libguestfs: for Java bindings
                  extra/libjpeg-turbo: for TurboJPEG Java wrapper
                  extra/libjxl: for JNI bindings
                  extra/libreoffice-fresh: adds java support
                  extra/libreoffice-still: adds java support
                  extra/libsvm: for java bindings
                  extra/nomad: for java driver
                  extra/nomad: for java driver - headless
                  extra/octave: java support
                  extra/opencv: Java interface
                  extra/opencv-cuda: Java interface
                  extra/polymake: java module
                  extra/ruby-concurrent: jruby support
                  extra/spring: java-based bots
                  extra/swi-prolog: for using Prolog from Java
                  extra/texlive-binextra: for utilities like arara, texplate
                  extra/texlive-latexextra: for pdfannotextractor
MakeDep For     : extra/chromium
                  extra/cvc4
                  extra/electron23
                  extra/electron27
                  extra/electron28
                  extra/electron29
                  extra/electron30
                  extra/mysql-workbench
Package Size    : 41.18 M
Download Size   : 0.00 B
Installed Size  : 187.41 M
Packager        : Tomasz "Ludvick" Niedzielski <ludvick0@gmail.com>
Build Date      : 2024-04-27 18:28:47
SHA-256 Sum     : 0774c9869fea600a38be28641ffaa5fea27befd820801960b5f8f019102f6962

?

FYI /[/]|:/ = /[/:]/.,

Do you want to exclude exactly local/libbluray: BD-J library or any line that starts with local/libbluray: or any line that ends with BD-J library or any line that starts with local/ or something else? Do those lines ONLY occur in the Optional For section or can be elsewhere too? Make sure to add the sample input that produces the output you show to the question so people can copy/paste it to test a potential solution with.

Any line that begins with local/. I think, occurency of local/ might depend on the exact package (jre is just an example).

Please state that in your question. Never add information in comments where they can't be formatted and could be missed, make sure ALL of the information we need to help you, including sample input, expected output, and all requirements, is in your question. And if those lines to be deleted can appear in the sections you wanted compressed in your original question, make sure to include instances of those cases in your input/output too as they might require different handling than the un-changed sections.

If it might appear in other sections too then include it in other sections too in your sample input/output as your code doesn't treat all sections the same way. Take the time to create a minimal complete example that demonstrates all your needs and can be copy/pasted as-is to fully test a potential solution.

Assumptions:

remove all values (2nd column) that start with local/

One idea would be to skip adding an entry to the vals[] array if the value starts with local/; modifying OP's current code:
#### replace this:

vals[++numVals] = substr($0,valInBeg)

#### with this:

val = substr($0,valInBeg)
if (! (val ~ /^local[/]/) ) vals[++numVals] = val

We're not given a sample set of input so I came up with the following after reviewing OP's previous question:
$ cat pacinfo.out
Name:           puddletag
Base:           puddletag
Repository:     local
Version:        2.3.0-2
Description:    An audio tag editor for GNU/Linux
Architecture:   any
URL:            https://docs.puddletag.net/
Licenses:       GPL-3.0-or-later
Groups:         modified
Requires:       python-certifi
Requires:       python-charset-normalizer
Requires:       local/first_occurence
Requires:       python-configobj
MakeDep for:    python-certifi
MakeDep for:    python-certifi
MakeDep for:    local/thing: 1 2 3 4 5
MakeDep for:    python-certifi
Optional For:   python-levenshtein: faster duplicate matching
Optional For:   local/something: 1 2 3 4
Optional For:   python-lxml: additional tag sources
Optional For:   python-pyacoustid: AcoustID support
Required By:    extra/bcprov
Required By:    extra/beanshell
Required By:    local/other_thing: a b c
Required By:    extra/cfr
Package Size:   0.00 B
Download Size:  0.00 B
Installed Size: 4.84 M
Packager:       Tomasz "Ludvick" Niedzielski <ludvick0@gmail.com>
Build Date:     2024-05-11 03:22:46
Install Date:   2024-05-11 03:23:57
Install Script: No
Install Reason: Dependency
Validated By:   SHA-256
Validated By:   Signature

NOTE: there are 4 occurences of local/ in the above data set
Running OP's modified code against this data set generates:
Name            : puddletag
Base            : puddletag
Repository      : local
Version         : 2.3.0-2
Description     : An audio tag editor for GNU/Linux
Architecture    : any
URL             : https://docs.puddletag.net/
Licenses        : GPL-3.0-or-later
Groups          : modified
Requires        : python-certifi python-charset-normalizer python-configobj
MakeDep for     : python-certifi python-certifi python-certifi
Optional For    : python-levenshtein: faster duplicate matching
                  python-lxml: additional tag sources
                  python-pyacoustid: AcoustID support
Required By     : extra/bcprov
                  extra/beanshell
                  extra/cfr
Package Size    : 0.00 B
Download Size   : 0.00 B
Installed Size  : 4.84 M
Packager        : Tomasz "Ludvick" Niedzielski <ludvick0@gmail.com>
Build Date      : 2024-05-11 03:22:46
Install Date    : 2024-05-11 03:23:57
Install Script  : No
Install Reason  : Dependency
Validated By    : SHA-256 Signature


Thank you @markp-fuso for your time spent for the answer. This is what I exactly needed.
